# Checkout page in Opencart is not working

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to sort out the error but i was not, my checkout page is disabled, how i don't know. I have not made any changes in the coding, so no chance of coding issue. is there any setting to be changed, i search also refereed some tutorials but there is only an option to disable and enable the guest checkout.
Here is the link where I get the issue
[OpenCart website link](http://civiltechrealty.com/demo/chip/)

Comment: i can get to the checkout page fine?http://imgur.com/I7Wnmbs

Comment: you need to go to products and select any product category and the add any product to cart and there you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. You have a problem in the file, checkout section works heavily with javascript. Just checking through browser console I understood there is a syntax error in one of the files which prevents the page to work (terminates Javascript Engine).

The error is:

```
textColor = textColor.slice(4);
```

In line `26` of file:

```
script.js
```

Debug the above variable to see why it errors. The file is stored in `jQuery/sidemenu` of the Javascript directory of your catalog theme.